# Is it ok to model a computation as a web resource (REST resource)?

Tags: http, rest

Let's say I have a component wich performs an addition as a business operation. 
I don't need the result of the sum to be persisted anywhere because, let's say, the only thing that matters is the result of the addition.

Let´s say that the client component should get interested in saving the result of the addition, so I need to indicate the client how to save the result of the addition, so he can come back later and retrieve this result.

May the addition service be modeled as a web resource? Something like:

```
GET api.mycompany.com/addition?param1=x&param2=y
```

should return the result of the business operation. The response may present the following as a link (here comes the hypermedia) to persist the result:

```
POST api.mycompany.com/addition?param1=x&param2=y
```

Is this approach correct? -In the sense of a truly restful api -

Answer (score 0):

Considering CRUD operations, this one:

```
GET api.mycompany.com/addition?param1=x&param2=y
```

Is idempotent, safe and cacheable, so I'll consider it as a RESTful GET.
As soon as your parameters become more complex, you could POST them to your 'addition' resource, returning a URL to computed result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is fine. But perhaps it is better to have a resource called `operation` that returns a list of links to supported operations. You could then have `operation/addition?param1=x&param2=y` and so on and so fort. Of course, the links should be opaque and the documented media-type returned by a call to the `operation` resource should provide information about the other available resources.

Comment: Thank you Vicin. Do you believe in verbs in the url?

Comment: I think they are ok if they identify a resource, but in general I would shy away from them. That said, the `add` above should be `addition`; I will modify my answer.